# how to highlight a specific area on chartjs line chart

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using `chartjs` to draw a line chart on my application. I have dates on`x-axis` but as a category scale. Means labels are strings but are `dates`. On the y-axis i have numeric values. I am changing the chart on some functionality and after change i want to highlight some area of the chart. Is there any way i can highlight an area on the line chart? I have searched but did not find anything.

I want to do this pragmatically like there are some specific dates which i want to highlight so i want to have this type of effect.

[image]
Any kind of help would be much appreciated. I am very beginner in charts and `javascript` stuff.

P.S this is specifically for the `line chart` not for the `doughnut`

Comment: @Artier This is not a doughnut chart.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244698/chart-js-line-chart-with-different-background-colors-for-each-section

Comment: @Artier Mate i dont know why you are giving me the links but not reading my question. This is in chartjs1. Secondly ok i want to change the background but how ? My questions are not addressed in both questions you have given me.

Comment: To everyone who googled this: [here's a much better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108389/how-to-make-rectangle-in-chart-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation lib to do something like this.check on it. I think this will helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But will it fill the color between the charts. ?

Comment: @fatpotato I think you can do it. This is sample https://codepen.io/compwright/full/mmQMrZ/

Comment: Let me test this

Comment: It is nice to hear @fatpotato .

Comment: This is nice, but can we get a title over the highlighted area?